# I am facing this exception - CannotResolveClassException, org.apache.jmeter.control.SwitchController

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

Trying to launch Jmeter via Java code in Maven project,
Jmeter version 5.1. \Using ApacheJmeter_core-5.5 dependency

I am trying to launch Jmeter in non-gui mode

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, it's nigh impossible to figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test is using a [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) - you will need to add [ApacheJMeter_components](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_components) library to your project [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Also be aware of [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) which might be a way easier option

If you need an example of using Maven for running a JMeter test programmatically via API - check out [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) sample project

Comment: Adding ApacheJmeter_Components Dependency worked for me. Thank you!!